# Bash robocopy from text file containing path to folders and files to copy with special characters

Tags: bash, file, escaping, robocopy

I had a bash xcopy script, but got a lot of issues. After a lot of searching and reading I guess robocopy was a better tool to do the copy.
(The script must run on windows 10 computers without installing anything else and without internet access)

I'm trying to make a bash script that copy (with robocopy) some local network folders and files to a local custom directory. The aim is to be able to access to the files off from the local network.
The path to folders and files are stored inside a txt file (each line = a path)
I want to keep the structure of folder I save locally.
For example the folder X:\Path\to some\local\network\folder\with\some & characters\ will result in C:\PathTolocalFolder\Path\to some\local\network\folder\with\some & characters\ (without the X:\ letter)

Based on many similar questions (but not all at the same time) I have done this :

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
cls
cd C:
chcp 28591 > nul


for /f "delims=*" %%a in ('type "X:\path with spaces & specials characters\List.txt"') do (
    REM echo %%a
    REM echo !%%a!

    echo %%a to C:\PathTolocalFolder!%%a!
    ROBOCOPY "%%~a" "C:\PathTolocalFolder!%%a!" /S /A+:RA /R:1 /W:5
    )
```

It is partially a success, but :

1. As there are special characters everywhere in paths and files names, I got some issues. Specially with & characters. My double quotes doesn't solve the problem.  How could I go better?
2. For some cases, I want to save some files but not the whole directory where they are. The full path to the file is inside the text file. But as robocopy needs to add a space between folder path and file filter I have do some manipulation. How can I detect and extract the file name when there is one to adapt the robocopy command?
3. I want to use an exclusion list like I was doing before with xcopy. But robocopy doesn't accept a file in input for exclusions. I tried this to extract the exclusion file:

   for /f "usebackq tokens*" %%D in ("C:\path to exclusion file\exclusions.txt") do (
   if NOT "!dirs!"=="" (
   Set dirs=!dirs! "%%D"
   else (
   Set dirs ="%%D"
   )
   )

But doesn't really know what I am doing and how to combine with the first part.

4. Bonus questions I'm using the robocopy log file functionality (removed from below) is there a way to archive (by adding the date in the name for example) previous log file before creating the new one? Is it possible to remove the progress percents in the log file but to display it in the terminal instead? How to use the "/np" option for log file but not for terminal display?

It's hard to me to understand how the delayed variables are working in batch files and how the different methods to read a file or variable are working.

Any help is welcome :)
Sorry for my bad English skills
thank for having read